# mysql error with a large union: Incorrect key file for table '#sql_24b3_61.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysql-error-126

I am doing a sitewide - query across a large wordpress MU installation. I am getting this error:

> Incorrect key file for table '#sql_24b3_61.MYI'; try to repair it

The table signified, `sql_24b3_61` is not part of my db. Also, the query is very large as it queries across many tables.

It seems to be some configuration setting?  because when I shorten the query by almost half it works. I have set `open-files-limit` to 10000, but that did not change anything.

Comment: The table signified is a temporary table MySQL creates to serve your query. Is your query / the temporary table perhaps to large for the tmpdir? If so, what happens if you set it to a disk/path with a lot more room?

Comment: Thank you this was in deed the case! thanks so much

Comment: the tmp folder has a limit usually 2GB, try df -h to see it